# Find constants A and B to satisfy the differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, trigonometry

Find constants $A$ and $B$ such that the function
$y = A \sin x + B \cos x$ satisfies the differential equation $y'' + y' - 2y = \sin x$.

**My attempt:**

$$y' = A \cos x - B \sin x$$
$$y'' = -A \sin x - B \cos x = -y$$

So we have
$$y'' + y' - 2y = -y + y' - 2y = -3y + y' = \sin x$$
$$-3 (A \sin x + B \cos x) + A \cos x - B \sin x = \sin x$$
$$-3A \sin x -3B \cos x + A \cos x - B \sin x = \sin x$$
$$ -3B \cos x + A \cos x = 3A \sin x + B \sin x + \sin x$$
$$ \cos x(-3B + A) = \sin x(3A + B + 1)$$
$$ \cos ^2 x(-3B + A)^2 = \sin ^2 x(3A + B + 1)^2$$

I've tried a bunch of stuff from here, like using $\sin ^2 x + \cos ^2 x = 1$ to get rid of all the cosines, but I can't get anywhere. I'd appreciate any help/hints.

Thanks!

Comment: Its pretty straight forward:......After calculating $y''+y'-2y=c_1 \cos x+c_2 \sin x \space \text{(say)}$ solve for  $c_1=0,c_2=1$

Comment: Since $\tan x$ is not a constant function, there is no way you can find such constants $A$, $B$, unless both sides are $0$.

Comment: For $x=0$ you get $-3B+A=0$, and for $x=\pi/2$ you get $0=3A+B+1$.

Comment: **Hint:**

The equation
$$-3A \sin x -3B \cos x + A \cos x - B \sin x = \sin x$$
is equivalent to 
$$(-3A-B)\sin x+(A-3B)\cos x=\sin x$$

The last equation holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ iff $\color{blue}{-3A-B=1}$ and $\color{blue}{A-3B=0}$.

Comment: thank you everyone, I understand it now!